# Use Excel file as a Resource file for Java Program

Tags: java

Is it possible to Use Excel file as a resource bundle for java program?

Comment: Downvote seems a little harsh, upvoting it back to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Maven, there is [a Maven plugin](http://redkangaroo.bitbucket.org/maven/properties-files-mojos/) which claims to be able to do this (note that it is using XLS rather than XLSX format files). If you're not using Maven, you could still have a [peek around the source](https://bitbucket.org/redkangaroo/properties-files-mojos/src/) for some ideas.

If you really need to load the resources from an Excel document at runtime, you could create your own [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class that delegates to [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hpsf/todo.html) or another library capable of reading Excel files, but that seems like it might be a lot of work.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into using these Google code resources:

http://code.google.com/p/nlstools/

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't have thought so.  Java expects Resource Bundle's to be a text file containing key/value pairs, not an Excel file.

You could maybe write a something to turn an Excel file into a ResourceBundle at build time?

Comment: You're thinking of PropertyResourceBundle which is a ResourceBundle subclass using property files.  prasun can implement a ResourceBundle subclass using Excel files as indicated by ig0774 in the latter part of his answer.